# Azure Kinect - Setting World Scale

Tags: scale, kinect-v2, azurekinect

I'm trying to get body tracking to register on small action figures that are about 12" tall. I've tried using other depth sensors like the Zed2 and D435i and their skeletal SDK's recognize the toys as "humanoid" and attempt to track the skeleton.

Is it possible to change world scale or a filtering option so that the Azure Kinect or Kinect v2 do not ignore the toys?

Answer (score 0):

I reached out to Microsoft and this was their response:

" AK Body Tracking has been tuned to process human’s from 7-8 years and up in age. The action doll is being filtered out as too small. They currently don’t expose the tuning parameters. They will considering exposing the tuning parameters but they have nothing to announce at this time. "

Unfortunately a no go at the moment.